# LIKE clause applied to a DB Type in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created the following Type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.expressions
AS TABLE
(
  expression varchar(255)
);
GO
```

How can I, in a Stored Procedure, use the n types that I receive and do, with each one, an select with a like clause?

In terms of "programming" (and pseudo-code), would be something like this:

```
for each expression in expressions
rows+=select * from table where table.field LIKE '%' + expression[i] + '%'
```

I can always call the SP multiple times from my API but I was wondering if this is possible, and even faster, to do in SQL side.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is `rows`?  What does `+=` mean with `select *`?

Answer (score 5):

You simply *SELECT from / JOIN with* an instance of the type. Assuming you have something like:

```
CREATE TYPE expressions AS TABLE (expression varchar(255));
CREATE PROCEDURE mysp(@expressions AS expressions) ...
```

You can use the variable like you would use a table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @expressions AS expressions
INNER JOIN yourtable ON yourtable.field LIKE '%' + expressions.expression + '%'
```

The above will allow you to use `expression` in select clause. Otherwise you can use the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM @expressions AS expressions
    WHERE yourtable.field LIKE '%' + expressions.expression + '%'
)
```